# Half of a Mean-Value Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, laurent-series

For an entire function $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n \, ,$$
we simply have that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(Re^{it}) \, {\rm d}t = c_0$$
$\forall R>0$. The same is true if $R\rightarrow 0$, but we only consider a finite arc $\theta<2\pi$. Now I'm wondering if anything can be said about
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^\pi f(Re^{it}) \, {\rm d}t = \pi c_0 + 2\pi i \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\, \sum_{\substack{n=1 \\ n\text{ odd}}}^\infty \frac{c_n R^n}{n} $$
so for half a circle instead.

In particular I'm interested in the case for which this expression is equal to $0$ for $c_0=0$. Can you come up with a function $\neq 0$ for which this is the case? For example $$f(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{\log z}, \frac{e^z-1}{\sqrt{z}},...$$
would satisfy this property, but these, unfortunately, are not entire.

If instead I approach this from the RHS, i.e.
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_{2n+1}}{2n+1} \, R^{2n+1} = 0 \, ,$$
then $$c_{2n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} (2n+1)$$
would give $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_{2n+1}}{2n+1} \, R^{2n+1} = Re^{-R^2} \, .$$

Comment: what about any even entire function for which $f(0)=0$ (eg $\cos z-1$, $e^{z^2}-1$ etc

Comment: Well, that's not what I expected, but it certainly works :-). Any idea about the question, whether general statements can be made about the limiting integral?

Comment: not sure what kind of statements you want; it is easy to find examples where the limit is infinity or oscillates just by picking appropriate $c_n$ for $n$ odd (eg $c_n=1/(n-1)!$ gives infinity and $c_n=(-1)^{(n-1)/2}/(n-1)!$ gives oscillation